# How to include Google Play Services to my project without help of any IDE?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to determine correctness of the Google Play Services when my app starts. So I include

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
```

into my main activity file.
Then I've:

- installed Play Services (and Google Repository as described [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split)) via Android SDK Manager;
- put `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.+'` into my build.gradle
- added

  ```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  ```

  into AndroidManifest.xml

But when I'm trying to compile the project, I get this error:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')
```

I've found out that one way to solve it is to copy google-play-services_lib into my project folder and then add a link to it into project.properties file. But I have only /docs and /samples folders in sdk/extras/google/google_play_services. There is no such google-play-services_lib at all!
I don't use any IDE, my project is builded from CMake files, so any IDE plugins won't work for me...

How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: You need the manifest merger process to resolve your issue. That is available from the Android Plugin for Gradle, when you use Gradle as your build system. You are welcome to see how other build systems (e.g., Buck) handle this, and see about upgrading your CMake-based build system to match. "I've found out that one way to solve it is to copy google-play-services_lib into my project folder and then add a link to it into project.properties file" -- that is a legacy Eclipse solution, and Google no longer supports that.

Comment: @CommonsWare could you please provide some link or explanation on how manifest merger can resolve my issue? For now I simply don't know what to search...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe I've been already lost for humanity, but I don't understand how manifest merger could help me. I've tried `<uses-library
android:name="com.google.android.gms.play-services"
android:required="true" />` but no succes.

Comment: "I don't understand how manifest merger could help me" -- libraries have their own manifests. The Play Services library has a manifest with the missing `<meta-data>` element, along with lots of other things that you are missing. Build systems that implement manifest merger will take contents from all relevant manifests and merge them together. Your chosen build system does not. Most likely, the answer is for you to not use Play Services. "I've tried..." -- that has nothing to do with Play Services or most other libraries. That is for manufacturer-supplied libraries in firmware.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for detailed answer, I'll try to determine Google Play Services version in another way

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in ur app gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // ...
}
```

and the last line of app gradle as:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also refer https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Google Services Plugin, but I still get same error.